# Poincaré duality for smooth projective varieties over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, etale-cohomology, reference-request

What is exacly the statement of Poincaré duality for smooth projective varieties over finite fields and twisted constant $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ sheaves? Where can I find a proof?

By twisted constant $\mathbf{Z}_\ell$ sheaf, I mean a system of $\mathbf{Z}/\ell^n$-sheaves that are constructible and étale locally constant, e.g. the system $(\mu_{\ell^n}) = \mathbf{Z}_\ell(1)$.

I'm interested in the *finite field* case of Poincaré duality. Presumably, the formulation is something like $H^i(X, F) \times H^{2d+1-i}(X, F') \to H^{2d+1}(X, ?) = \mathbf{Z}_\ell$. Now, I want to know what $F'$ and $?$ is.

**Edit**: One should even have for smooth separated connected varieties $U$ pure of dimension $d$ have a duality $H^i_c(U,\mathscr{F}) \times H^{2d+1-i}(U,\mathscr{F}^\vee(d)) \to H^{2d+1}_c(U,\Lambda(d)) = \Lambda$.

Is there an abstract nonsense proof using derived categories like "if there is a duality for $f$ and $g$, there is a duality for $g \circ f$" (applied to $X/\overline{\mathbf{F}_q}/\mathbf{F}_q$)?

Comment: The phrase "twisted constant" sounds funny. Since you make simplifying assumptions ("projective" rather than "quasi-projective"), do you also want $\mathbb{Q}_ {\ell}$-sheaves instead?  The answer is simpler in that case since then both sides of the duality use cohomology, without Ext's (but to *prove* the result one uses torsion sheaves, and hence Ext's). Or is the point of the question precisely to not invert $\ell$, and/or to encode a Galois-equivariance condition (since you mention non-sep. closed base field)? Please clarify your motivation so it is clearer what properties matter to you. 

Comment: I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Let $X_s = X_ {k_s}$, $F_s = F_ {k_s}$ on $X_s$.  Since you avoid Ext's, you must require the stalks of $F$ to be free, so I will assume this.  By Leray the natural map $H^i(X,F) \rightarrow H^0(k,H^i(X_s,F_s))$ is surjective with kernel $H^1(k,H^{i-1}(X_s,F_s))$.  In particular, $H^{2d+1}(X,\mathbf{Z}_ {\ell}(d)) = H^1(k,H^{2d}(X_s,\mathbf{Z}_ {\ell}(d)))$. Thus, using trace map and $G_k \simeq \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}$, this is $\mathbf{Z}_ {\ell}$. So try $? = \mathbf{Z}_ {\ell}(d)$, $F' = F^{\vee}(d)$, and look for orthogonality in cup products. Try Artin-Mazur, or Milne ADT, for dimension 1?

Comment: What's the title of Artin-Mazur? What do you mean by $F^\vee$ and what by "look for orthogonality in cup products"?

Comment: By $F^{\vee}$ I mean linear dual, as in usual Poincare duality (you don't want Ext's, so you need freeness on $F$-stalks). Contemplate the cup product and the Leray filtrations: maybe sub's annihilate each other and pair perfectly against the cokernels? That would do it...hmm, cohomology could have torsion, so you ought to invert $\ell$; otherwise the Ext's come up. See Zink's Appendix 2 of Haberland's Galois cohomology book for $S$-integers of number fields (with ref. to Ann. ENS notes of Mazur), and Google "Artin-Verdier duality"; adapt it to *curves* over finite fields. Check Milne's ADT.

Answer (score 6):

The main case can be found in [Milne's article](http://jmilne.org/math/articles/1986a.pdf) specifically Theorems 1.13, 1.14 on page 310. 
The idea, briefly, is as follows: Given a sheaf $F$ on a variety $X$ over a finite field $k$, then over an algebraic closure $\bar{k}$ of $k$, the group $H^i_{et}(\bar{X}, F)$ becomes a $Gal(\bar{k}/k)$-module. There is a spectral sequence involving the $H^j(Gal(\bar{k}/k), H^i_{et}(\bar{X}, F))$ which converges to $H^n_{et}(X,F)$. This is true over any perfect field.

When you have duality over $\bar{k}$ (e.g. $X$ smooth proper and $F$ nice), combine it with duality in Galois cohomology (in our case, the group is very simple: $\hat{Z}$) to get duality over $k$.
The duality theorems now reflect the $k$: if Poincare duality for $X$ of dimension $d$ over $\bar{k}$ pairs $H^i$ with $H^{2d-i}$, over $k$ the pairing will be between $H^i$ and $H^{2d +m -i}$ where $m$ is the cohomological dimension (assumed finite) of the Galois group ($m=1$ in the case of a finite field).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know about Theorem 11.1 in Milne's book Étale cohomology. It is over a separably closed field though (i.e. not finite).

Comment: Yes, I'm interested in the finite field case.

Answer (score 1):

One can adapt the proof for curves over finite fields in Milne, *Étale Cohomology*, Corollary V.2.3.

Is there an abstract nonsense proof using derived categories like "if there is a duality for $f$ and $g$, there is a duality for $g \circ f$" (applied to $X/\overline{\mathbf{F}_q}/\mathbf{F}_q$)?